# Audio in Rails using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, audio

I have inserted javascript inside one of my views: **...../show.html.erb**
I have also set timeout of 5s to play the audio which is in my public directory and the file is called bowel.m4a.
How do I insert code inside the js to play the audio ?

Here is my view file:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p>
<h4><center>Welcome   <%= @person.name %></center></h4>
</p>
<%= audio_tag("welcome.m4a", autoplay: true, controls: false) %>
<center><%= image_tag("trump_family.png", size: "800x800") %></center>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(
function(){ 
    // Play audio
      var audio = new Audio('bowel.m4a');
      audio.play();
    // 

 }, 5000); 
 </script>
```

Comment: Try to add your audio file to /audios/welcome.m4a. With autoplay attribute audio_tag should start automatically begin playback as soon as it can do so. For start playback from js you can document.querySelector('audio').play() if I correct understand your question.

Comment: The welcome.m4a plays well.The problem is the bowel.m4a, which is also in the same directory  /audios/ . I need to play the bowel inside the setTimeout

Comment: Try var audio = new Audio('/audios/bowel.m4a')

Comment: not working either.

Comment: Are there any errors in browser console?

Comment: It works now. Thanks for your help